# raspi-config activating WiFi "verbose" output

Tags: raspi-config

See the addendum for "short version" of this post.

I am trying to understand processes / files used in initializing WiFi. 
I know that wpa_suppllicant.conf is part of the process. 
To verify that I used raspi-confing option to implement WiFi and checked the contents of wpa_supplicant.conf file for changes. It did not change. .
I went back to raspi-config and changed WiFi country, rebooted and again checked the wpa_suppllicant.conf. The country DID NOT change.

As part of my tests I changed to ubuntu MATE , unfortunately there was no option to implement WiFi, but I noticed when some other options were actually  being configured I saw what appeared as terminal output in the background of the desktop.

Two questions - 
am I looking at correct wpa-supplicant.conf in /etc/wpa_supplicant directory ?
Is there a way to actually get "verbose" output from raspi-config to see what is being implemented?

Thanks 
appreciate any help

ADDENDUM

OK, found "source " on git hub 
**So how do I find it in Raspian and add "echo " to it??**

Comment: "which raspi-config" will show you where the executable lives.

Comment: `So how do I find it in Raspian and add "echo " to it?` .... have you checked for any log files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> found "source " on git hub So how do I find it in Raspian and add "echo " to it??

Check `which raspi-config`.  Pretty sure it is `/usr/bin/raspi-config`.  There's probably not much point in adding any `echo`, since if you can figure out where to put them, you'll be figuring out what it actually does (follow the menu options, the main one is I think at the bottom, you can then search the script for the function calls).

Comment: Yes, found the file. I need to learn how to do grep ...My next post is going to be " my RPi  won'r boot..." after I get thu modifying.